# nextjs conditional jsx not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

Up in my component I have:

```
 let isClicked = false;
```

Down where things are rendered I have:

```
<div className="relative">
   {!isClicked ? (
    <div className="relative">
       1
    </div>
    ) : (
    <div className="relative">
       2
    </div>
    )
   }
</div>
```

The issue is nothing changes when the variable changes.
I can ensure the variable changes on the command line.
And the logic works if I change it and manually reload the page.

The issue is it won't re-render when the variables changes during the run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special variables in react that cause rerender on their change. These are state variables. Imagine the problem you will face if every variable change causes a rerender.

If this is a functional component you can make use of `useState`:

```
const [isClicked,setIsClicked] = useState(false);
.
.
//some method triggered by button click etc.
const onclick =() => {
setIsClicked(true);
}
.
.
```

Read : [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

Comment: Can you explain how the setIsClicked works? Thank you. Also why must the onclick function be inside where the render function is, why can't it be outside that block?